# How to make the firefox webdriver browser window to the very front of the desktop

Tags: window, webdriver

I'm writing automation tests with Selenium 2.0, in Java, Win7 platform. In some situation, I need the firefoxdriver window to be in front of all windows on the desktop, not only windows of the firefoxdriver but also the mannually opened ones(eclispe IDE e.g.).
Is there some way to do this?
I've investigated this for 2 days, maybe I'll need some Windows API? Any comment, big welcome

Answer (score 2):

I use python, and I got what I want by:

```
self.selenium.execute_script('alert(1);')
alert = self.selenium.switch_to.alert
alert.accept()
```

Hope this help someone later.

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me. You might want to mention that `switch_to_alert` is now deprecated and `switch_to.alert` should be used instead.

Comment: @Farhan.K modified

Answer (score 1):

This should help with positioning the window. It should come into focus once the tests are running.

```
   webDriver.Manage().Window.Position = new Point(screenPosition, 0);
   webDriver.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(width, height);
```

Answer (score 1):

python:

```
webdriver.execute_script('window.focus()')
```

Java:

```
webdriver.executeScript('window.focus()')
```